# An example of two Gaussian random variables which are not equal almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory

In page 71 of [these](http://www.princeton.edu/~rvan/acm217/ACM217.pdf) lecture notes it is stated:

> ...$X$ and $X'$ being (zero mean, unit variance) Gaussian random variables does not mean $X=X'$ almost surely. ...

I've been trying to construct an example of the above but I haven't gotten very far--so could someone please post an explicit example of such two random variables. That is, an $X$ and $X'$ that map from some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ such that for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

$$\mathbb{P}(X\in A)=\mathbb{P}(X'\in A)=\int_A \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$

but such that $X\neq X'$ on a set of positive probability.

---

Update: A silly addition to universalset's answer, an explicit example then is $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\mathbb{P})$ with $X(\omega)=\omega$ and $X'(\omega)=-\omega$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the Gaussian measure:

$$\mathbb{P}(A):=\int_A \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}dx$$

Comment: Not quite an explicit example, but if you have one such random variable $X$, then $-X$ is a.s. *not* equal to $X$ and has the same distribution.

Comment: Although this is not an answer, if you find an example of two i.i.d. Gaussian random variables $X, X'$ then you're done.

Comment: Just take two independent R.V....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite an explicit example, but if you have one such random variable $X$, then $−X$ is a.s. not equal to $X$ and has the same distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on constructing one on a probability space.

Take $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ under which $X$ is a normal random variable.

Take $(\Omega',\mathcal{F}',P')$ under which $X'$ is a normal random variable.

Then consider the product space and the product measure...